# Not able to run Grid views in swift ui

Tags: xcode, gridview, swiftui, lazyvgrid

Xcode Version - 12.5
Swift Version - 5.4

code (ContentView.swift)
[image]

When I try to run this code I get and error in SceneDelegate.swift as follows
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `contentView` to `ContentView()`. Case-sensitive.